# Skip a specific line using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote this code to read a text file and I am running into a problem where it skips the 4th line rather than a line that meets the condition.

Here's my code:

```
    while(fileReader.hasNext()) {
                        String label = fileReader.nextLine();
                        String prompt = fileReader.nextLine();
                        String message = fileReader.nextLine();
                        
                        if(fileReader.nextLine().contains(label)) {
                            fileReader.nextLine();
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println(label);
                        System.out.println(prompt);
                        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

The prompt that I am trying to read is this. In this case, I want to skip every line that contains information about the number of children a node has. (Line 4(root 3) and 14(1 3))

```
root                                       // Will always be "root"
Root Node                                  // Will never be displayed to screen
What Model is the Washing Machine?         // Message
root 3                                     // Number of children for label root: 3
1                                          // First child. Label
WM200                                      // First child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // First child. Message
2                                          // Second child. Label
WM300                                      // Second child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // Second child. Message
3                                          // Third child. Label
WM400                                      // Third child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // Third child. Message
1 3                                        // Number of children for label 1: 3
1-1                                        // Label
No Water.                                  // Prompt
Is the hose attached?                      // Message, etc.
```

Desired Output:

```
root                                       // Will always be "root"
Root Node                                  // Will never be displayed to screen
What Model is the Washing Machine?         // Message
1                                          // First child. Label
WM200                                      // First child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // First child. Message
2                                          // Second child. Label
WM300                                      // Second child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // Second child. Message
3                                          // Third child. Label
WM400                                      // Third child. Prompt
What is the problem?                       // Third child. Message
1-1                                        // Label
No Water.                                  // Prompt
Is the hose attached?                      // Message, etc.
```

And I am getting the following output from my code:

```
root                                     
Root Node                                 
What Model is the Washing Machine?         
1                                           
WM200                                       
What is the problem?                        
WM300                                       
What is the problem?                       
3                                          
What is the problem?                        
1 3                                         
1-1                                         
Is the hose attached?
```

So my code ends up skipping every fourth line rather than only those lines that meet the condition.

Comment: Your conditions under which a line is to be skipped are not clear, at least not to me. It might help if you could show the desired output in addition to your current output.

Comment: My apologies I have made the proper edits for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You read the line in the `if` condition without storing it
you should use:

```
while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    String label = fileReader.nextLine();
    String prompt = fileReader.nextLine();
    String message = fileReader.nextLine();

    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(label)) {
        line = fileReader.nextLine();
    }

    // continue your logic with the stored line
    System.out.println(label);
    System.out.println(prompt);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to skip the line was because the label, prompt, and message contain the information stored in a node of a binary tree. So I am not sure how to assign the String value of line to label during the next loop call. To clarify more, the text that follows after each number following the root represent a new node that is the child of the root. So in this case, the value stored in line would be the label value for node 2

Comment: @CosmicPioneer i suggest storing label outside the loop and make the check at beginning of the loop if the nextline contains label ignore it else assign this line you just read to label
BTW the scanner may throw an exception if node doesn't have at least three lines

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to rebuild a Tree which has been persisted (breadth-first) into this text. The question you ask is not the correct one as the data is not being read correctly. Looking at the text and your comment ...

```
 1 3                                        // Number of children for label 1: 3
```

Clearly this is nothing to do with the label of node 3 appearing a few lines before. Your data format is:

- **Node** uses *3 lines* only
- **Children** block starts with "parent count" followed by `count` **Node**s.

Try this:

```java
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+) (\\d+)"); // Header is "<parent-label> <count>"
    String parent = null;
    
    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
      String header = fileReader.nextLine(); // new stanza - could be Node or Children
      Matcher m = regex.matcher(header);
      if (m.find()) {
        // Handle Children
        parent = m.group(1);
      } else {
        // Handle Node
        String label = header;
        String prompt = fileReader.nextLine();
        String message = fileReader.nextLine();

        System.out.println(String.format("%s/%s %s %s", parent, label, prompt, message));
      }
    }
```